# Flutter - how to get AppBar title foreground color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Flutter app, where on the `appBar`, I have added a dropdown button. My app supports primary / secondary color changing.
The screenshot below shows an `appBar` for two different primary colors. 
[image]

As you can see, the Flutter is able to decide what color to use for app bar text to keep proper readability - white for dark color and black for light color (second app bar).
I would like to set dropdown items' text color identical for the one, used by Flutter app bar text, hence, I would like to retrieve it.
Looking at `Theme.of(context)` properties, however, didn't give me a clue what color should I use to achieve what I need to.

Below is the code snippet:

```
final ThemeData _theme = Theme.of(context);
final int index = values.indexWhere((TimeSpan element) => element.value == initialValue.value);
return Theme(
  data: _theme.copyWith(
    canvasColor: _theme.primaryColor,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton<TimeSpan>(
      items: values
          .map(
            (value) => DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(
                value.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(color: _theme.colorScheme.surface),
              ),
              value: value,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onChanged: callback,
      isExpanded: false,
      value: values[index],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I think you can explicitly do that.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: code snippet added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple of days working with light / dark theme brightness, I figure out, a (possible) solution for the above case. 
You can get the desired text color via one of the existing text themes, for instance `Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.title.color` returns color adjusted to current theme brightness.

Comment: In latest Flutter this can be found at:
`Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.titleMedium?.color`

Answer (score -2):

Flutter renders the widget based on the final theme values it has.

So for example if the child widget has a different theme and the parent widget has a different theme, Flutter's rendering engine will first give preference to the child widget's theme over the parent widget's theme.

So `DropdownButton` has a theme hardcoded by default which cannot be directly changed as the widget does not accept any parameter to change the theme of the underlying widget(s) and as a result the Theme of the parent widget won't change/alter the theme of DropdownButton. That's the reason why the text Week remains black in both the cases.

If you really want to change the theme you can either alter the source code of `DropDownButton` or make a custom widget for it. However, simply hardcoding the values for text-color should still do the work.

In order to change the Appbar's text color you will have to manually change the text color as the parent theme suggests that the text color should be white whereas you want it to be black(as per your requirements).

```
Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Weight Overview",color: Colors.black)
  )
[...]
)
```

On OP's request,

You can manually change the Theme of your children at any point of your Widget tree by using the `Theme` widget and providing it with a `theme`.

Solution code:

```
Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Theme(
    theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.black),
    child: Text("Weight Overview",),
        ),
  ),
[...]
)
```

Comment: I don't think the above answers my question, actually. I know how to change `DropdownMenuItem` text color, as it is clearly stated into above code snippet see `style: TextStyle(color: _theme.colorScheme.surface)`. What I am struggling to find out is how to get the `appBar` text color, which then I can apply to the `DropdownMenuItem`. This is actually my question.

Comment: Read the answer as whole to get a more better understanding of what I am trying to convey.

Comment: The question I asked has a very simple answer. What I expected to see is e.g. `Theme` property, which I can use to retrieve the desired color. Your answer suggests to change Appbar color which is not what I need, hence your answer does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I have updated my answer assuming as per your requirements.

Comment: Just to recap - my question is "how to get AppBar title foreground color" (see the title), rather than answering it, you suggest to change AppBar title color, which obviously is not what I am asking for.

Comment: Oh sorry. Just give that Text widget a GlobalKey and use that key to get the color you were looking for.

Comment: Man, the whole point is how to GET `appBar` text color. All the time you are telling me how to SET it, which is not what I am asking for.